# How to avoid values from an object after inserting from an input form to be inserted repeatedly?

Tags: javascript

I am inserting the values of an input into an array of objects. Then, I want to get those values e show inside the HTML. Inserting each value inside the object is not the problem, every time I click the button, each value is successfully added. When I `console.log()` the array, it shows only one of each value added. The problem is when I try to show the content of the object inside the HTML element, it inserts all the data from the object over and over again, but I just want to add the last value added and keep what was previously inserted, not to add everything again.

What am I doing wrong?

This is my HTML

```
    <main>
      <div class="add-recipes">
        <form id="form">
          <h2>Add Recipe</h2>
          <div class="input-wrapper">
            <div class="text-input-wrapper">
              <label for="title"
                >Title
                <input type="text" name="title" id="recipe-title" />
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button id="send-recipe-btn" type="submit">Send Recipe</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="recipes-container"></div>
    </main>
```

This is my JS File

```
let recipes = [];
const addRecipe = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let recipe = {
        title: document.getElementById('recipe-title').value
    };
    recipes.push(recipe);
    document.querySelector('form').reset();
    recipes.forEach(e => {
        const recipeContainer = document.querySelector('.recipes-container');
        const recipeTitle = document.createElement('div');
        recipeTitle.classList.add('recipe-title');
        recipeContainer.append(recipeTitle);
        recipeTitle.textContent = e.title;
    });
    console.log(recipes);
};

document.getElementById('send-recipe-btn').addEventListener('click', addRecipe);
```

Thanks for any tip or help to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the `forEach()`loop to start before `recipeTitle.textContent = e.title;`

```
let recipes = [];
const addRecipe = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let recipe = {
        title: document.getElementById('recipe-title').value
    };
    recipes.push(recipe);
    document.querySelector('form').reset();
        const recipeContainer = document.querySelector('.recipes-container');
        const recipeTitle = document.createElement('div');
        recipeTitle.classList.add('recipe-title');
        recipeContainer.append(recipeTitle);
    recipes.forEach(e => {
        recipeTitle.textContent = e.title;
    });
    console.log(recipes);
};

document.getElementById('send-recipe-btn').addEventListener('click', addRecipe);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your event handler, you are looping over the `recipes` array and creating a new element every single time the button is pressed.

Just remove the loop and it will work properly